# Best practice to deserialize a JSON using Spring MVC

Tags: java, json, spring-mvc, serialization, deserialization

I'm developing a web application using Spring MVC; it works as follows:

1. a JSON request is created from a model object (a POJO)
2. it's sent to an external server that exposes some APIs
3. a JSON response is received by the controller

I need to figure out which is the best way to serialize and deserialize JSON in a Java web application. At first I was using Gson but then I began to wonder if it was the right choice.

1. Is it possible to serialize and deserialize JSON to/from model
   object using @RestController annotation? How does it works? I only find examples of how to create a rest service, in this sense
2. What is the best practice in this case? RestController? Gson? Jackson? Other?

**N.B.** My JsonResponse object has a generic field because the responses are all the same except that for a value. An example:

**AccountRequest.class**

```
public class AccountRequest() {
    private String jsonrpc;
    private String method;
    private Map<String, Object> params;
    private int id;

    //constructor, getters and setters
}
```

**JsonResponse.class**

```
public class JsonResponse<T> {
    private String jsonrpc;
    private T result;
    private String id;

    //constructor, getters and setters
}
```

**LoginResult.class**

```
public class LoginResult {
    private String token;
    private String product;
    private String error;
    private Date lastLoginDate;

    //constructor, getters and setters
}
```

**MyController.class**

```
@Controller
public class LoginController {
    String response;
    [...]
    @RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView doLogin(@ModelAttribute("user") User user) {
        [...]
        //???
        [...]
    }
}
```

I open connection, send request and save the response in response String in MyController class. User parameter is annotated with @ModelAttribute to retrive the User object created by the showLoginForm() method.

Using Gson I know how to serialize request from my model object:

```
AccountRequest accountRequest = new AccountRequest();
accountRequest.setJsonrpc("2.0");
accountRequest.setMethod("method");
accountRequest.setParams(params);
accountRequest.setId(1);

String gson = new Gson().toJson(accountRequest);
JSONObject accountRequestJson = new JSONObject(gson);
```

And how to deserialize response in my model object:

```
Type jsonType = new TypeToken<JsonResponse<LoginResult>>() {}.getType();
JsonResponse<LoginResult> jsonResponse = new Gson().fromJson(response, jsonType);
```

The response is now saved into jsonResponse object, and I can put it in my ModelAndView.

Now, how can I deserialize it in my model object using @RestController and Jackson? Can you confirm it's the better method to do that? Can you post an example?

I hope it's not a silly question.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: As you was saying, @RestController is the answer. The default lib used in SpringMVC is Jackson. Also, you can change it if you want.

Comment: You omitted the important part: The way to `response`.

Comment: Thank you for your answers. @zeroflagL What do you mean with "the way to response"? The JSON response matches perfectly with my model object. I can't understand the logic behind RestController annotation in my case. I edited my answer

Comment: You mention the steps 1, 2 and 3 but there is no corresponding code in your question. Yet that is where the magic happens. `@RestController` is not involved here.

Comment: I've edited my post yesterday: the last quote contains the code I used to deserialize the response; the response is a String I get after a normal HttpRequest to an URL; now I added the code I'm actually using to serialize a JSON. I did not post that piece of code because, actually, I'm using Gson. I think I figure out, however, that the standard in Spring is to serialize and deserialize JSON using RestController and Jackson2 (I'm right?), therefore now I'd like to know the logic between these.